# Ethernet does not connect when WiFi is enabled

Tags: wireless, networking, 13.04, ethernet

Ever since upgrading to 13.04 I have been experiencing a rather weird phenomenon. At the office, we primarily use Ethernet, but there is also a WiFi network in the building (lets call it `wifix`). If I want to use the Ethernet rather than `wifix` I must make sure my laptop has booted with wireless disabled; if wireless is enabled it will connect to `wifix` during bootup, and the Ethernet will somehow not work. Even if I then disable wireless after booting. So to get Ethernet to work, I must disable wireless, and ***reboot*** my machine. This means I must remember to disable wireless each time I shut down my laptop. Or else I must reboot just to get the freaking Ethernet to work.

There must be a way to fix this, but how?

Answer (score 0):

Try executing this command

`echo on | sudo tee /sys/class/net/eth0/device/power/control`

it usually solves all ethernet-related issues